# How can I factory reset my Android Mini 7100 Phone?

Tags: recovery-mode, factory-reset, hard-reset

I'm unable to go to recovery mode to factory reset (wipe my cache/data) my [Android Mini 7100 Phone](http://www.aliexpress.com/w/wholesale-mini-7100.html) (Android GingerBread 2.3.x) because I forgot my phone lock combination.

I tried resetting it using:

- Vol Down + Power,
- Vol Up + Power,
- Vol Up + Vol Down + Power,
- Vol Up + Vol Down + Home + Power,

and the phone starts normally

- When I press Home + Power, it goes to 'Test' mode.

I checked out [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PDAHpz6HICQ) but it did not work for me.

How do I go to recovery mode?

Comment: Normally, if you enter your password wrong a few times, and you've tried or can't unlock it with your Google account, it just offers to factory reset from the lock screen. Might this be an easier solution for you?

Comment: @DanHulme Thanks for the comment but the only options are Sign in and Emergency call. I don't know the gmail account used too.

Comment: How many Gmail accounts do you have? ("my Android Mini 7100 Phone" vs. "I don't know the gmail account used" seems a little contradicting)

Comment: @Izzy Sorry for the confusion. The phone was my sisters and she forgot password of the gmail account she used. That's why. Any solutions to get into recovery mode?

Comment: Personally not. But you might [look here](https://www.google.com/search?q=android+mini+7100+hard+reset) and watch a bunch of youtube tutorials on this (people often confuse the factory-reset with the hard-reset, though the latter is rather corresponding to "power unplug").

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest (and non-sketchiest) solution for this will be to help your sister recover her Gmail password. Once you have that, you can use the [Android Device Manager](https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager) to reset the phone password, or erase the phone memory from the computer.

[image]
This is the only solution I will post here because resetting an android without access to a gmail account is often done with less-than-ideal intentions.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are missing or failing to do something very important:

1. Switch off your Phone
2. Press and hold the Vol Up + Vol Down + Home + Power buttons together until a dead Android image no command shows up
3. Press the power button to show recovery options
4. Navigate with the volume up button
5. Select and choose "Wipe data and factory reset"
6. Scroll to "YES" Use volume down button to choose. Wait till data
   wipe is complete.
7. Now, select "Reboot system now"

Answer (score -2):

Did you try ADB?, there may be a chance your device can be recognized by adb although its locked.

If adb can see your device than run the below command and wipe data and factory reset

`adb reboot recovery`

Comment: this only works if the user has enabled usb debuggin